# Non SSL connection to gmail using node-imap

Tags: node.js, imap

I am trying to connect to gmail using [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) module. The following code throws timed out error.

```
var Imap = require('imap');
var imapConnection = new Imap({
    user: process.argv[2],
password: process.argv[3],
host: "imap.gmail.com",
port: 993,
debug: console.log
});
imapConnection.connect();

{ [Error: Timed out while connecting to server] source: 'timeout' }
```

Note: If I gave `tls:true` and `tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false}` it is connecting well. How to connect to gmail without SSL.

Additional information : My node version is v0.10.25

Comment: I can't say for sure, but Gmail could very well require `SSL`. Why do you need to connect without it?

Answer (score 2):

Gmail requires SSL. They do not allow plaintext connections.

Answer (score -1):

Try as below:

```
var Imap = require('imap');
var imapConnection = new Imap({
user: process.argv[2],
password: process.argv[3],
host: "imap.gmail.com",
authTimeout:300000, // increased to 5 mins
port: 993,
debug: console.log
});
imapConnection.connect();
```